# What does the musical note sort feature, and the numbers below it, on Google Music mean?

Tags: google-play-music

When you are looking at your playlist, there are a few sort features; Name, Time, Artist, Album, a musical note, and Rating.

What does the musical note mean, and what do all the numbers below it mean? At first I thought it was counting how many times I've listened to each but that doesn't seem to be it either. I can't find anything about it anywhere on Google Music Help or online.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it has to be the number of times the song has been played. I just played a song in one of my playlists and the number incremented by one. (I did have to get about a minute in before it ticked over, though.)

I'm really rather baffled why there's not a tooltip or any help that describes it.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one confused by it! lol  I'll have to keep an eye on it, I didn't think it was counting up as I played a song, but maybe it's only when you actually click to play it? I have some on my list with no numbers next to them that I know I've listened to, but maybe not directly clicked on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to have listened to them through the Google Play player, and possibly while using that list.

Comment: Ah! I typically use the web player. It seems less consistent with that. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems to make sense that they are the number of times a song is played. That might also be why the same songs are played over and over on shuffle. The system recognizes that we must like it if we have listened to it a lot.